# Converting SQL to LINQ using Group By and Max

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

Is it even possible to write the following query using LINQ? I've been fighting all day, :(

```
select * from ProductGroup pg 
Inner join (
    select max(DateShipped) as ShipDate
        , ProductId
    from Lot lt
    group by ProductId) lte
    on pg.ProductId = lte.ProductId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution1**

I tested this on LinqPad using LinqToSQL.

```
var data = from lt in  Lots            
           group lt by lt.ProductId into grp
           join pg in ProductGroups on grp.Key equals pg.ProductId
           select new { pg.ProductId,pg.ProductName,ShipDate =grp.Max (g => g.ShipDate)};

data.Dump();
```

and it produced this SQL (almost like your sql , just order of tables is switched)

```
SELECT [t2].[ProductId], [t2].[ProductName], [t1].[value] AS [ShipDate]
FROM (
    SELECT MAX([t0].[ShipDate]) AS [value], [t0].[ProductId]
    FROM [Lot] AS [t0]
    GROUP BY [t0].[ProductId]
    ) AS [t1]
INNER JOIN [ProductGroup] AS [t2] ON [t1].[ProductId] = [t2].[ProductId]
```

**Solution2**

This is one way to force a correlated sub-query which produces same result as you want but without a join/group by

```
var data = from pg in ProductGroups
           let sd = Lots.Where (l => l.ProductId == pg.ProductId ).Max(l => l.ShipDate )
           select new { pg.ProductId,pg.ProductName,ShipDate =sd};

    data.Dump();
```

and it generated this SQL

```
SELECT [t0].[ProductId], [t0].[ProductName], (
    SELECT MAX([t1].[ShipDate])
    FROM [Lot] AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[ProductId] = [t0].[ProductId]
    ) AS [sd]
FROM [ProductGroup] AS [t0]
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a bit. But I have to include 2 fields on Group By clause in the 1st table and pull another item from 2nd table, I had to modify slightly to run okay in LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = (from pg in ProductGroup
                join lte in
                (
                    from lt in Lot
                    group lt by lt.ProductId into gr
                    select new
                    {
                        ProductId = gr.Key,
                        ShipDate = gr.Max(x => x.DateShipped)
                    }
                )
                on pg.ProductId equals lte.ProductId
                select new
                {
                    ID = pg.ProductId,
                    MaxShipDate = lte.ShipDate
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't know if this is meant to be pseudocode or some real language, but whatever it is, it's not C#.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used a 2nd grouping and picked the most recent item, took me a while but I have it now.